# Is it possible to concatenate a sequence of n outputs coming from the same ConvNet and output them into a second network without having to store them?

Tags: keras, neural-network, concatenation

I have a classifier `VGG16` and I'm feeding it with the crops of an image obtained by dividing the image in grids (3x3). So I input in sequence 9 crops of the same size `(224x224)` and per crop, I collect the output of `fc7`, shape `(4096,)` and I store it.

Then I concatenate the 9 outputs in a Tensor of shape `(9, 4096,)` and I feed it into an LSTM that threats the 9 crops as timesteps.

This is the flow of a single image, but of course, I have multiple images. So I have to process the 9 crops per image, store all the feature maps and then create a new dataset that consists of all the concatenations.

Is there a way to make it end-to-end? So basically process the 9 crops in once and input a Tensor of size `(9,4096,)` directly in the second part of the network?

I'm using **Keras** with Tensorflow backend.

Comment: One way that I can think of (without having tried it) is to set the batch size of the first network to 9 and thus process 9 crops simultaneously. You could then use [`map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) to apply the LSTM to each patch. I becomes a bit hacky if you want the network to process batches of images though, then the batch size needs to be multiples of 9 (e.g. 27 for 3 images, etc).

Comment: I had this idea as well but I think it is not very reliable. Especially if for some reason 9 crops cannot fit in the memory of the GPU the whole thing breaks.

Comment: That's true of course but I would assume that the memory of a modern GPU (> 8GB) should suffice to accomodate VGG16 and a batch size of 9 for images of `224x224`.

Comment: But reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094171/train-a-cnn-lstlm-end-to-end) I came to think you could just sequentially feed the patches one by one into your CNN and your LSTM afterwards (without any gathering operation). This way you have end to end training wihtout any batch size.